# Autoscaling group application load balancer health checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I'm trying to put my autoscaling groups behind an [application load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/) (not a classic ELB) and was wondering if it is possible for my autoscaling group to use an application load balancer to health check its instances.

I want instances the application load balancer deems unhealthy to automatically be terminated and for the autoscaling group to create a new one.

What i've found currently happens is my target group marks instances as unhealthy but I am unable to get the autoscaling group to use the ALBs health checks, is this possible?.

Attempting to edit load balancers field on autoscaling group:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can.

When a **Load Balancer** detects an unhealthy instance, it simply stops sending traffic to the instance. It does not terminate the instance.

When **Auto Scaling** detects an unhealthy instance, it terminates the instance and automatically replaces it to maintain the **Desired Capacity**. However, the default health checks performed by Auto Scaling only look at the underlying health of the virtual machine -- it is not able to check the health of applications.

Fortunately, you can **combine health checks between Load Balancing and Auto Scaling**. This way, if the Load Balancer detects an unhealthy application, Auto Scaling can terminate and replace the instance.

Be careful! If the health checks are incorrectly configured, it may cause **thrashing** (continually adding and removing instances). For example, if an insufficient **warmup period** has been specified, Auto Scaling might terminate an instance before it is fully ready.

See documentation [Health Checks for Auto Scaling Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/healthcheck.html):

> If you have attached a load balancer to your Auto Scaling group, you can optionally have Auto Scaling **include the results of Elastic Load Balancing health checks** when determining the health status of an instance.

[image: Auto Scaling health check]

Note:

- When using a **Classic Load Balancer**, Auto Scaling uses the health check from the Load Balancer
- When using an **Application Load Balancer**, Auto Scaling uses the health check from the **Target Group**

The Application Load Balancer will not appear in the "Load Balancer" list within the Auto Scaling group configuration. Instead, select the appropriate **Target Group**.

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear John (i've updated it) but i'm using the new application load balancer not a classic ELB and I am struggling to get my autoscaling group to use health checks for the ALB, and I was wondering if this is possible or not. Thanks

Comment: Answer updated for the Application Load Balancer (ALB).

Comment: My autoscaling group has an attached target group which is correctly reporting an unhealthy instance however the autoscaling group is still reporting this instance as healthy (seems to be using ec2 checks).

Comment: Did you use **Health Check Type = ELB**? In thinking about it, I wonder if a failed health check on a **Target Group** would cause the instance to be replaced, given that it might be provisioned via a Container? We're in new territory here!

Comment: Yep health check type = ELB on the autoscaling group. Not too sure what else to try - it seems to me like the functionality just isn't there at the moment. Thanks for your help

Comment: I tested and **Auto Scaling DOES kill instances from an ALB Target Group health check**. I created: ALB with Target Group, ASG pointing to Target Group, Health Check Type = ELB. The health check for the Target Group failed, and the ALB correctly terminated my EC2 instance, replacing it with another. Took a few minutes, though.

Comment: I've just tried with completely new resources and this does indeed work. My other resources I created through the CLI there must be something I missed. Thanks for all the help John!

Comment: What about NLB, what is the functionality there?  Can't find anything in the docs about this.

Comment: @rix Please create a new Question instead of asking via a comment on an old question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974281/terminate-unhealthy-instances-in-asg-behind-nlb

Comment: Out of curiosity, while using ELB health check with target groups, failing health check will terminate the whole instance & we have few other services(target groups) running on the same instance which we do not want to get removed during that time since they are passing the health check. I understand that it will resurrect but  is it really a good idea? How should we solve this problem?

Comment: @vivekyad4v Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 5):

I have been able to recreate my problem by creating an autoscaling group **but not attaching the target group at creation time.**

Instead, after the autoscaling group had a running instance I editted its settings to attach a target group to the autoscaling group. When I did this the instance would not correctly register as unhealthy in the autoscaling group.

Comment: This just bit me as well. Seems like a bug in AWS

Comment: At best the documentation is poor on this issue - It's not clear on the subtleties; but generally excellent.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue where my CodeDeploy blue/green deployment would clone my ASG and discard the Target Group setting, later on even if I reattach the target group to the new ASG the ELB health check won't work, as in my instance would be "unhealthy" according to the ELB but "healthy" to the ASG. Did you find any workaround?